# Transportation of texture to already modeled object

Tags: texturing, uv

I've tried to transport a texture from textures website to my already modeled bag. As you can see on the sides it didn't show up properly as opposed to front side, what should I do?[image]

Also, on different faces of front side texture haven't laid out evenly, what should I do in this case as well?

[image]

Comment: you need to mark seam along the sides and unwrap again

Comment: Problem solved: I selected faces along the sides in edit mode and clicked UV unwrap faces -> Smart UV project. Hope it will help someone in the future.

Comment: sure, Smart UV Project works as long as your map changes when you have angles

Comment: UPD: Its better to click UV unwrap faces -> Unwrap - for seamless texture on sides.

Thanks @moonboots for suggestion.

Comment: "I've tried to transport a texture from textures website to my already modeled bag." like what do you mean by "transport"? Importing it directly from the website?